# foreach loop not working on use state hook reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

On button click i am trying to use forEach loop for my use state hook which is initially an array.

my hook is:

```
const [regrowsData, setRegrowsData] = useState([])
```

my button code is:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => regenrateRows()}>Add Row</Button>
```

function that changes data of useSate hook:

```
const regenrateRows = () => {
        var newArr = regrowsData;
        newArr.push('newvalue');
        setRegrowsData(newArr);
    }
```

function on which i want to forEach regrows state array.

```
var getRows = () => {        
        
            regrowsData.forEach((row) => {
               
                alert(row)
            })
       
    }
```

Problem is on change of state, there is no alert msg appears.

Comment: can you show us where ```getRows``` function is called

Comment: Try using `map()` **instead** of `forEach`, it always works for me

Comment: return (
            <Paper elevation="2">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => regenrateRows()}>Add Row</Button>
                <Table style={{ overflowX: "scroll", display: "block" }}>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {getColumns()}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {getRows()}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Paper>
        )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is because you are using mutable data.
Try changing your `regenarateRows`function to this:

```js
const regenrateRows = () => {
        setRegrowsData([...regrowsData, 'newvalue']);
    }
```

Comment: if i want to update the state Five times only..?

Comment: I didn't understand the question..you want to limit the count of add row clicks? If so, you probably will need another state to count the times state has changed or check regrowsData.length before calling setRegrowsData. Btw, regenrateRows is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the same reference to the state, which is why react not able to find the changes.

Try like this

```
const regenrateRows = () => {
     regrowsData.push('newvalue');
     setRegrowsData([...regrowsData]);
}
```